# "Akasam Lingamityahu..." which Purana is the source of this verse?

Tags: shiva, puranas, shiva-lingam, shloka

I have a small book on Lord Shiva called "Shiva Tattva Pradipika".

In the final chapter of the book i found the verse in question. The author says its a Puranic verse but does not mention which Purana contains it. The verse extols the greatness of Shiva Lingam.

> AKasam LingamityAhuhu Prithivi Tasya PeethikA |
>
> Alayaha Sarva DevAnAm LayanAllinga Muchyathe ||
>
> ### Meaning
>
> Akasha is called the Linga. And Prithvi  its Peethika ( or the
>   Yoni Peethika or Gauri Vedika ). The Akasha is famous as the Linga as
>   its the home of all Gods and as it is in which everything ends (or go to at their end ) ( Laya ).

Question- Which Purana is the source of this verse?

Comment: At least I know similar sloka from Linga Purana 'Sarvam Lingamayam Lokam, Sarve Linge Pratisthitam... '

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The verse is from Skanda Purāṇam. The [Śabda Kalpa Drumaḥ](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%83/%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%9C) states that the verse from Skanda Purāṇam though the particular khaṇḍa or samhita is not stated.

> लिङ्गव्युत्पत्तिर्यथा, --
>
> “आकाशं लिङ्गमित्याहुः पृथिवी तस्य पीठिका । 
> आलयः सर्व्वदेवानां लयनाल्लिङ्गमुच्यते ॥”
>
> इति स्कन्दपुराणम् ॥

Comment: Until i get something better i am selecting this.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this verse is found with a slight variation in [this chapter](http://read.84000.co/#UT22084-051-004/part%20one) of a Buddhist text called the Karandavyuha Sutra:

> akasam lingam ity ahuh prithivi tasya pithika | 
>   alayah sarvabhutanam liyanal lingam uchyate ||
>
> It is said: the sky is his liṅga, 
>  
>   The earth is his seat. 
>  
>   He is the foundation of all beings. 
>  
>   The liṅga is so called because they dissolve into it.

The verse you're referring to, though, has "sarvadevanam" or "all gods" rather than "sarvabhutanam" or "all created beings".  In any case, concerning the "sarvadevanam" verse, in [this excerpt](https://preview.ibb.co/iB9uT5/image.jpg) from his book "The Origin of Om Manipadme Hum", Alexander Studholme cites other authors who claim that the verse is from the Skanda Purana, but says that he was not able to find it himself:

> With regard to the couplet, it is, to say the least, unfortunate that Regamey was unable to give a precise reference for this verse in the Skanda Purana, having come across it not in any edition of the text itself, but in a modern anthology of Indian religious scriptures compiled by Alain Danielou.  Danielle notes only that it appears in the Skanda Purana.  The task of pinpointing the two lines is made somewhat difficult, not only because of the vast size of this purana, but also because it exists in several different editions.  Like Regamey, I, too, have failed to discover the exact location of the couplet.

I've found many other books that claim this verse is from the Skanda Puranas, like [this one](https://books.google.com/books?id=S1HkAAAAMAAJ&q=ahuh+tasya+linga&dq=ahuh+tasya+linga&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiS1JjAid7TAhVMQyYKHTIoADIQ6AEIHDAA) and [this one](https://books.google.com/books?id=rQJuAAAAMAAJ&q=alayah+sarvadevanam&dq=alayah+sarvadevanam&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2pvHmid7TAhXLOSYKHYVpAYEQ6AEIJDAB), but none that specify its location. As Studholme suggests, this may be a verse that is found in some recensions of the Skanda Purana and not others.